# How to implement Dockerfile inheritance?

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile which installs production & test dependencies. I want to have separate image for tests, so production image is smaller, without to much code duplication. Maybe there is something like `FROM` statement for referencing other Dockerfiles?

Dockerfile has following lines:

```
ADD requirements.txt ${PROJECT_DIR}/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache --process-dependency-links --trusted-host github.com -r requirements.txt
ADD requirements-test.txt ${PROJECT_DIR}/requirements-test.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache --process-dependency-links --trusted-host github.com -r requirements-test.txt
```

First two install depencencies for project, second two - install dependencies for testing (pytest, pylint, etc.).

I also have docker-compose that starts database, redis cache, etc. This is how I run service and run tests:

```
run:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml run
test:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yaml run py.test tests/
```

Inside both `docker-compose.yaml` has this build config for my container:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

So, I could reference different Dockerfiles from my `docker-compose.yaml`, but I don't want them to be complete copies that have only two lines difference.

Comment: You can use `docker-compose` to compose one or more files to run with. For example: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml build`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The recommend method is multistage builds:

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

That is dont separate production from test docker files. Instead keep all the requirements in one file and build for the target stage you need.

An example Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.7-slim-buster AS production
ADD requirements.txt ${PROJECT_DIR}/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


FROM production AS test
ADD requirements-test.txt ${PROJECT_DIR}/requirements-test.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements-test.txt
```

and then for your production build target the correct stage:

```
docker build --target production -t org/service:latest .
```

Multistage build syntax was introduced in Docker Engine 17.05.

Comment: Nice! I think that method existed at the time when I asked this, but it never came to me that it could be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

`FROM` is the way to go here. Production and development images should not differ too much, or at all, since the idea is to deploy what you have developed. In my experience it is easier to start with a production image and extend a development image from that, since development requires more software like debuggers, compilers, etc.

Due to the comment:

Within a `dockerfile` the `FROM` directive takes an image tag, so something like `ubuntu:latest` and then docker will first try to find that image locally, and then try to pull it from a repo, if it is not found locally.

In case you do not have a repo, you can create the base image locally by running:

```
docker build --tag vendor/production:0.0.1 .
```

that will compile the image. Than you can write:

```
FROM vendor/production:0.0.1
```

in your `dev-dockerfile` and compile this. I usually create a tiny bash script for all the compilation stuff.

Comment: Yes, it would be logical to extend production. But how to do that? Can I tell docker to start `FROM Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to not use Docker Compose to build images, then you can manually build it in two steps:

`Dockerfile.test` might contain:

```
FROM prod-image
RUN pip install more-dependencies
```

Then run:

```sh
docker build -t prod-image .
docker build -t test-image -f Dockerfile.test .
```

This having been said, best practice is generally to only have one image, and to run things like end-to-end tests against your production image.  Where I have tests that rely on additional tooling or libraries (code-coverage tools, unit-test libraries, mock object factories) I (and my CI system) run them outside of Docker, but against the same code base.  There is only one image (per build) that gets run in developer-oriented, test-oriented, pre-production, and staging environments.

Comment: So you're saying all the test artifacts should be in the shipped image?

Answer (score 1):

[There is an issue in github regarding what you want](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/735)